# replacements for big int in rust

Tags: rust, factorial

I made a program to calculate the prime numbers of 1 to n in python and rust. Surprisingly python wins with the difference of `0.008` and `0.590`. Rust won all other questions with the difference of `0.001` and `0.008`.

The only difference here, is that I need to calculate a large number. Python is fine with large numbers, but rust requires a crate knows as `num`. Without using the `num` crate, rust wins.

Is there some how that I can avoid using `num`, without changing my solution?

Here are the rust and python solutions.

```py
from functools import reduce
fact = lambda x: reduce(lambda y, z: y*z, range(1,x+1))
is_prime = lambda x: False if x <= 1 else fact(x-1) % x == x - 1
primes = lambda x, y: tuple(filter(is_prime, range(x,y+1)))

import sys
print(primes(1, int(sys.argv[1])))
```

```rust
macro_rules! number {
    (+ $($args:tt),*) => {
        num::BigInt::new(num::bigint::Sign::Plus, vec![$($args),*])
    };
    (- $($args:tt),*) => {
        num::BigInt::new(num::bigint::Sign::Minus, vec![$($args),*])
    };
}

fn fact(x: u32) -> num::BigInt {
    (1..x+1).map(|x| number!(+ x)).reduce(|x, y| x * y).unwrap()
}

fn is_prime(x: u32) -> bool {
    x > 1 && fact(x - 1) % x == number!(+ (x - 1))
}

fn main() {
    let n = &(std::env::args().collect::<Vec<String>>())[1];
    println!("{:#?}", (1..=n.parse::<u32>().unwrap()).filter(|x| is_prime(*x)).collect::<Vec<u32>>());
}
```

Comment: Probably the implementation of Python's bigint is faster than num's. So I would look up for a crate with faster bigint implementation.

Comment: By [this benchmark](https://github.com/tczajka/bigint-benchmark-rs), the fastest library seems to be [rug](https://crates.io/crates/rug), which uses libgmp.

Comment: How are running it? Make you you pass `--release` otherwise you'll run in debug mode without optimizations.